# Using Multiple 'If' Statements Correctly?

Tags: ios, if-statement, swift2

I have a static TableView as follows:

[image]

I want the UIVIew to have fixed height of 99 pixels, Info Bar cell of 30 pixels, Start & Timer Label of 70 pixels and Banner Cell of 50 pixels.

So I wrote the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {return 30 }
    if indexPath.row == 2 { return 70 }
    if indexPath.row == 3 { return 50 }

    else { return tableView.frame.size.height - 249 }
}
```

That way, Film Strip will always fill the balance of the available screen.

My code works. But I want to check if the way I have done it is acceptable in terms of 'code elegance'.

Is there a more acceptable way of coding for my desired result?

Many thanks ;)

Comment: Ask question here -> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Use switch case rather than if statement.

Comment: If using the "if" approach, I'd either delete the "else" on the last line or put "else" on the second and third "if" as well. As it stands, the logic is hard to follow because the else only matches that very last if.

Comment: @Eiko Thanks for the tip. I understand your comment, has helped me understand the if-else pattern a little more. For future cases I can adopt them. For my particular case, I have adopted the answer below - hugs to bneely ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might implement the same code like this:

```
var height: CGFloat = 0
switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: height = 30
    case 2: height = 70
    case 3: height = 50
    default: height = tableView.frame.size.height - 249
}
return height
```

Comment: Much more sexy. Thank you kind sir/madam ;)

Comment: Much prefer this approach, although I'd return the values directly instead of using a variable. Probably personal preference, but to me the logic is harder to track and verify here. Try both and ask "What's the result for row 2"? You'll have to understand (and overlook - as setting a completely irrelevant, never used number) the initialization, track the new value in your head associated with that variable, follow the path to see if something more happens to it, find the return, remember the value.

Comment: This approach uses an extra variable, but I prefer to use a single return statement when possible.